# jQuery.ajax empty resultset foobars my function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm running an ajax query against the Yahoo Boss API to get a list of the keywords contained in the search results.

However, I've found that when the data contains an empty value for keyterms (example: "keyterms":{}), my script breaks but does not trigger the error handler -> error: function()

I find that when the script breaks, alert(item['keyterms']['terms']) returns undefined

My code is below, what is causing the script to break when keyterms is empty and how can I force it to gracefully handle this condition?

```
        success: function(data)
            {
                var keywords = new Array();
                jQuery.each(data['ysearchresponse']['resultset_web'],
                        function(i,item) 
                            {
                            jQuery.each(item['keyterms']['terms'], 
                            function(i,kw)
                                {
                                key = kw.toLowerCase();
                                if (keywords[key] == undefined)keywords[key] = 1;
                                else keywords[key] = (keywords[key] + 1);
                                });
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I had to do in order to handle the exception...

```
function(i,item)
{
 if(item['keyterms']['terms']==undefined) item['keyterms']['terms'] = "" ;
 jQuery.each(item['keyterms']['terms'],
 // etc...
```

Comment: wouldn't it better to assign an empty array or just continue ?